# por que mi email automático no se envía?

Tags: php, email, post, autocompletar, mail

hola mi problema como dice el titulo es que necesito que se envíe una respuesta automática al mail ingresado en el formulario de la pagina escribí un código pero no se que estoy haciendo mal ya que la respuesta automática no se envía, me pueden ayudar?

```
if(isset($_POST['enviar']) && $_POST['email'] !==''){

  if(!empty($_POST['name']) || !empty($_POST['subject']) || !empty($_POST['message']) || filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   $name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
   $tel = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['tel']));
  $email = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
  $m_subject = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['subject']));
  $message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

  $to = "martoxxx100@gmail.com"; 
  $subject = "$m_subject:  $name";
  $body = "recibiste un nuevo email desde la pagina de Fácil Soft.\n\n"."detalles:\n\nNombre: $name\n\nTelefono: $tel\n\n\nEmail: $email\n\nAsunto: $m_subject\n\nMensaje: $message";
  
  echo'<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("mensaje enviado, gracias por contactarnos en breve nos estaremos comunicando");
        window.location.href="index.php";
        </script>';

  if(mail($to, $subject, $body)){ 
  $headerRep  = "Hola".$name."gracias por contactarnos nos estaremos comunicando a la brevedad. Atte Fácil Soft";
    mail($email,$headerRep);
  }else{
    http_response_code(500);
  exit();
  }
 }
}
error_reporting(0);

?>
```

Comment: Primero, ¿Por qué tu `echo` está fuera del `if`? Segundo, si lo que buscas es enviar un mensaje automático, ¿Por qué te envias a ti el mail primero? Tercero, ¿A ti te llega el mail con los datos del formulario?

Comment: el echo esta dentro del segundo if y cuando alguien presiona el botón enviar muestra ese mensaje, el primer mail que se envía a mi cuenta tienen los datos del usuario y el tercer if debería enviarle un mail al usuario que completo el formulario

Comment: En el segundo IF estas haciendo validaciones usando el operador logico OR, deberia ser AND?, entiendo yo de esa forma.

Comment: use OR para que si alguna de las opciones esta vacía de error si uso AND las 4 opciones deberían estar vacías para que me muestre el error

Comment: Tienes configurado un servidor de correos? El servidor / equipo tiene habilitado los puertos correspondientes?. Si no es el caso, tu email nunca saldrá a la luz. 
Intenta utilizar alguna librería como [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) y si no tienes montado un servidor de correos local, puedes utilizar el SMTP de google [Guía externa de referencia](https://kinsta.com/es/blog/gmail-smtp-servidor).

Comment: de hecho el primer mail si se envia a mi cuenta de prueba pero el segundo mail que seria el del usuario que se registro no me llega al mail

Comment: Intenta enviar el mail automático afuera del ```if(mail())``` Comenta este último y cuéntanos el resultado.